# Unable to reload collection view on successful image download

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I'm editing a record which has some text information and images. As I get images URL so I'm using SDWebImage to download images which are then displayed in a `collectionView` and it's vertical scrollable. So when the view is loaded I'm doing this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
for (index, _) in mediaFiles.enumerated()
                {

               let img = UIImageView()

            if let url = NSURL(string: "\(baseURLGeneral)\(mediaFiles[index].imageFile ?? "")")
            {
                print(url)

                img.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
                img.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)

                img.sd_setImage(with: url as URL, placeholderImage: nil, options: .refreshCached, completed: { (loadedImage, error, cache, url) in

                self.imagesArray.append(loadedImage!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async
                 {
                    self.photoCollection.reloadData()
                 }
                })

            }
    }
```

This code as per my understanding is downloading the image from web and when the image is loaded it add the image in an `imageArray` which I've declared as `var imagesArray: [UIImage] = []` and then reload the collection view.

As this is the edit screen so user can also add more images in `imagesArray` which will show with the downloaded images in the same array and can also remove images.

As per `collectionView` delegate and dataSource is concerned so I'm returning `return imagesArray.count` in `numberOfItemsInSection`.

In `cellForItemAt` after making a cell variable I've `cell.imageAddedByUser.image = imagesArray[indexPath.row]`.

**THE ISSUE** which I'm having is that after downloading images in `viewDidLoad()` `collectionView` is not getting refreshed. But If I `pop` and then `push` view controller it shows the images.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to call it in `viewDidAppear()`

`DispatchQueue.main.async { self.photoCollection.reloadData() }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to dispatch it in main Queue

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async
 {
     self.photoCollection.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: no this is not working and If I pop and then push view controller it shows the images. I've also updated the code in the question.